# Spring integration mybatis failed throws： java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory not present

Tags: mybatis

I had a problem when integrating the mybatis framework with spring. It seems that the versions of spring and mybatis are incompatible. I don’t know very well. Below is my pom file and error message，hope experts can help me.Thanks！

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bjpowernode</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_sm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>spring_sm</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
      <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

Error message：
`

```
2月 21, 2024 11:15:45 下午 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
警告: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory not present

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory not present

    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1211)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:517)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:465)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getFactoryBeanGeneric(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:916)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.bjpowernode.AppTest.shouldAnswerWithTrue(AppTest.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 45 more
```

I tried to modify the versions of spring-mybatis and spring-context but it didn't work

Comment: Spring 6 [requires](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range) JDK version 17 (not 1.7). If you are new to Spring and/or MyBatis, I would recommend using a small working project and making small changes one by one. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some project templates. Also, you might want to check out [mybatis-spring-boot-starter](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved.This problem is caused by Mybatis-spring 3.0.0 and Mybatis-spring1.0.0 differ in the configuration of the spring configuration file

Change the configuration property of SqlSessionFactoryBean in the spring configuration file to configLocation